# Which test method is running/executing at the moment?

Tags: c#, android, appium, visualstudio

I'm on Appium with C#, I have 60 test methods written on different classes.
I'm running the tests via Visual Studio test explorer.

When I click run all test button at the "**Test explorer**" it will start running the test cases, but not in an order. (I don't mind about the order). So how am I going to identify which test case is running at the moment.

*Can I get any indicator at the Appium GUI as a log or any other way?*

Comment: i am more into java, but is there any debugger you can use?

Comment: no i dont think so.Its having VS;s debugger.

Comment: I think there is a debugger available in VS, you can refer to https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging